# Do I need to check if a browser supports a certain event before adding the event listener

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, addeventlistener

I was just curious I came across the following package [Virtual Scroll](https://github.com/ayamflow/virtual-scroll). And in it when initializing they check for browser support before adding the event listeners. Like so:

```
if (support.hasWheelEvent) {
    this.#el.addEventListener(
        'wheel',
        this._onWheel,
        this.listenerOptions
    )
}
...ect for all events
```

and then the support object looks like:

```
export function getSupport() {
    return {
        hasWheelEvent: 'onwheel' in document,
        hasMouseWheelEvent: 'onmousewheel' in document,
        hasTouch: 'ontouchstart' in document,
        hasTouchWin: navigator.msMaxTouchPoints && navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 1,
        hasPointer: !!window.navigator.msPointerEnabled,
        hasKeyDown: 'onkeydown' in document,
        isFirefox: navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1,
    }
}
```

I was wondering if this is even necessary. Won't the browser just ignore it if it doesn't support the event specified?

I don't get any errors if I do the following in a non touch browser.

```
const onTouchStart = () => {}
document.addEventListeners('touchstart', onTouchStart)
```

Is there some kind of performance benefit for checking first or is there a chance of an error being introduced if you don't check for this?

Anyway let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Won't the browser just ignore it if it doesn't support the event specified?

In this example there is no difference (adding listeners), but sometimes you want to call a function that is not supported and it can lead to errors.

For example using [Battery Status API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API) isn't supported by Firefox, IE and Safari. Running this code in these browser will throw an error:

```
navigator.getBattery()
```

Checking if the function exists first fixes the problem:

```
if ('navigator' in window && typeof navigator.getBattery === 'function') {
  navigator.getBattery()
}
```

> Is there some kind of performance benefit for checking first or is there a chance of an error being introduced if you don't check for this?

No, as far as I know.

Comment: What do you mean when you say call a function that is not supported?